# Element API: return a related entry's asset data with entry data

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi

I'm producing a list of entries that each use an image asset from a related entry.  I see [in this ticket](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13236/4433) how to get an asset's data, and I've combined that with how I learned to output an object's data from a [Mijingo video](https://mijingo.com/lessons/creating-an-element-api-in-craft-cms/) (via the `array_map` function).

This approach works, but seeing how there are about 130 entries in the section, the load time is a whopping 2.31s versus when I take out the related entry's asset code, which then results in a much smaller 500ms load time.  Is there a better way to access this data?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/pressEntries.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'pressEntries'],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'id'                => $entry->id,
                    'title'             => $entry->title,
                    'slug'              => $entry->slug,
                    'postDate'          => $entry->postDate,
                    'type'              => $entry->type->name,
                    'url'               => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl'           => UrlHelper::getUrl("api/press/{$entry->id}.json"),
                    'relatedRecording'  => array_map(function(EntryModel $album) {
                        $data = [
                            'id'    => $album->id,
                            'title' => $album->title,
                        ];

                        $artwork = $album->recordingArtwork->first();
                        if ($artwork) {
                            $data['artwork'] = $artwork->url;
                        }
                        return $data;

                    }, $entry->relatedRecording->find()),
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do some [eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements) of your assets.

Here are some examples of how to do that in the Element API plugin:

[ElementAPI handling CategoryModel and returning a heirachical object](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15220/elementapi-handling-categorymodel-and-returning-a-heirachical-object/15228#15228)

[Getting categories in elementAPI performance issues and help required](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/getting-categories-in-elementapi-performance-issues-and-help-required/18177#18177)

Comment: Those articles were helpful, thanks Brad! I think I got it working now, but I ended up removing the `$artwork` bc I didn't need it in the end.  And for some reason I had to remove the `->find()`. Load time decreased by 2/3!